# Android OnClickListener inside services

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an image which is on top of all windows with android services and this is `onCreate` method:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mWindowsManger = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        mFloatingImage = new ImageView(this);
        mFloatingImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        mFloatingImage.setAlpha(0.5f);
        mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        mParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        mParams.x = 0;
        mParams.y = 100;
        mFloatingImage.setClickable(true);
        mFloatingImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                   System.out.print("clicked");
            }
        });


        mWindowsManger.addView(mFloatingButtonImage, mParams);
    }
```

My problem is `OnClickListener` not working instead `OnTouchListener` works .

Is there any way to implement `OnClikListener` in services ?

Comment: Are you dynamically created the ImageView?

Comment: Yes it's based on this tutorial http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/

Comment: I am not telling you the what wrong you have done.. You have to find it.. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mWindowsManger = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    mFloatingImage = new ImageView(this);
    mFloatingImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    mFloatingImage.setAlpha(0.5f);
    mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    mParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    mParams.x = 0;
    mParams.y = 100;
    mFloatingImage.setClickable(true);
    mWindowsManger.addView(mFloatingButtonImage, mParams);
    mFloatingImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
               System.out.print("clicked");
        }
    });

}
```

BUT I DO THIS RIGHT NOW IT WORKS FOR ME:

```
    rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    img = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);

    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            (int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

    img.setLayoutParams(params);

    rl.addView(img);

    img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Image Clicked",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Abhishek Das have given good answer. My answer is subset of his answer
Just you need to call :

```
mWindowsManger.addView(mFloatingButtonImage, mParams);
```

first and then :

```
mFloatingImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
           System.out.print("clicked");
    }
});
```

Before adding view to view hierarchy, the click listener may not work